# Python Four Digits Counter

Tags: python, counter

How do we use python to generate a four digit counter?

```
range(0,9999)
```

will have 1 digits, 2 digits and 3 digits. We only want 4 digits.

i.e. 0000 to 9999

Of course, the simplest Pythonic way.

Comment: Your `range()` call isn't actually producing 9999, but stopping at 9998.  This is because `range()`'s "end" argument is a less-than limit, as in "generate all numbers starting with 0 and less than 9999".  You need to use 10000 instead.

Comment: If you opt for string formatting, [please prefer](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) str.format(*args, **kwargs) to % formatting.`["{0:0>4}".format(i) for i in xrange(10)]`

Comment: I guess for portability. It is the current (Python 3) idiom for string formatting and it is available in Python >= 2.6 too. Excerpt from the page I posted previously: "This method of string formatting is the new standard in Python 3.0, and should be preferred to the % formatting described in String Formatting Operations in new code.".

Comment: The Python 2.7+ recommended formatting is actually "{:0>4}" (there is no need to add a positional argument).

Comment: @Guandalino: I think that you should put your comment in an answer: your format string is more up-to-date that the currently suggested one. :)

Comment: Out of curiosity, do any of the answers helped in some way? In this case, please check the winner!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Format the string to be padded with 0's. To get a list of 0 to 9999 padded with zeroes:

```
["%04d" % x for x in range(10000)]
```

Same thing works for 5, 6, 7, 8 zeroes, etc. Note that this will give you a list of strings. There's no way to have an integer variable padded with zeroes, so the string is as close as you can get.

The same format operation works for individual ints as well.

Answer (score 19):

Maybe `str.zfill` could also help you:

```
>>> "1".zfill(4)
'0001'
```

Comment: I guess this should have been the accepted answer. It is terse and is to the point. It worked really well.

Answer (score 5):

You don't. You format to 4 digits when outputting or processing.

```
print '%04d' % val
```

Answer (score 3):

if you'd like to choose string formatting, as many suggested, and you are using a Python not less than 2.6, take care to use string formatting in its newest incarnation. Instead of:

```
["%04d" % idx for idx in xrange(10000)]
```

[it is suggested](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to opt for:

```
["{0:0>4}".format(i) for i in xrange(1000)]
```

This is because this latter way is used in Python 3 as default idiom to format strings and I guess it's a good idea to enhance your code portability to future Python versions.

As someone said in comments, in Python 2.7+ there is no need to specify the positional argument, so this is also be valid:

```
["{:0>4}".format(i) for i in xrange(1000)]
```

Answer (score 0):

And to really go overboard,

```
In [8]: class Int(int):
   ...:     def __repr__(self):
   ...:         return self.__str__().zfill(4)
   ...:     
   ...:     

In [9]: a = Int(5)

In [10]: a
Out[10]: 0005
```

Comment: How do you obtain 4-digits numbers in range(0,10000) ? ``for x in xrange(Int(0),Int(1000))`` doesn't work.